# How to take input in XSLT?

Tags: discussion

I'm thinking of starting answering questions in XSLT, but I don't know what the standard method of input would be?

I'm thinking of an XML file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<input>Put your input here</input>
```

And then you access the input by using the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="input" />
</xsl:template>
```

What do the rest of you think?

Answer (score 1):

The option you listed above would work, however we also accept functions, so either of the following is valid as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!-- The following is a named template, which acts like a function -->
<xsl:template name="t">
    <xsl:param name="p">
</xsl:template>

<!-- The following is actual function in XSLT. -->
<xsl:function name="f">
    <xsl:param name="p">
</xsl:function>
```

As a side note, matched templates (as opposed to named templates) can also accept parameters, but requires more code to set them up.

Comment: This is much longer than taking input from a separate XML though isn't it?

Comment: `name` is shorter than `match` and `param name="p"` is shorter than `value-of select="p"`.  So, no, not at all.

Comment: So you don't count the template definition in your code? That could work

Comment: If you are referring to `<xsl:template match="/">`, yes I'm not counting it, because an XSL file doesn't need one.  It can simply create a function that other XSLT templates will import and call.